# How to get time difference while entering in two textbox and the result should be in other textbox in c#

Tags: c#

I need help to get the result of time difference.
Actually i will enter two time values in two textbox then difference should be calculated and display in other text box which already been in the form

Comment: can you at least show what you've worked on???

Comment: Actually am not getting any idea how to perform

Comment: In google i am geting only time diff code but i need result in the other textbox

Answer (score 0):

Like this, for example:

```
DateTime date1;
DateTime date2;
if (DateTime.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out date1) && DateTime.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out date2))
    textBox3.Text = (date2 - date1).ToString();
else
    textBox3.Text = "Invalid format";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn the basics first.

- [How to add textbox to Asp.net/WebForm](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_textbox.asp)
- [How to: Get and Set Values in TextBox Web Server Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts3ffwhk.aspx)
- [Date Time in C#](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime)

Let say a `TextBox` with the Id `demoTxtBox1` and another TextBox with the Id  `demoTxtBox2` are added to the form:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(Page.IsPostBack==false) //Page loads for the first time
{
 demoTxtBox1.Text ="Text test on page Load";   // Set text box value
 demoTxtBox2.Text="";
}
else{
     string textInTextBox1 = demoTxtBox1.Text; //Get text box value
     demoTxtBox2.Text = textInTextBox1;
 }
}
```